# send a value controlled by a jquery slider to the back end

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to send a value controlled by a jquery slider to the back end.

Front end:

```
 if (event.target.id == "slide1") {
                            $("#amount1").val(ui.value);
                            amt1 = $("#amount1").val();
                            document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = amt1;
                            console.log(document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value);

                        }

$("#amount1").val("%" + $("#slide1").slider("values", 0));

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

VB:

```
Session("Value1") = HiddenField1.Value
```

I use the console.log to monitor that the value does indeed change on the page. The problem is sending that value in a session.

On the follow page, i have a label that should display the text on load but does not.

Comment: Try setting ClientIDMode property of Hidden field with value 'static' i.e ClientIDMode="Static"

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work for me. it seems that i am able to send an integer value to the next page if i set it specifically. However, I cannot send a string for reasons unknown